# Can't render Flickerplate Slideshow on Meteor Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

I can't seem to properly rendered a slideshow using Flickerplate.js in my Meteor code. I'm adapting it from non-Meteor code.

My template for the slideshow div has the following code:

```
<template name="Slideshow">
        <div class="flicker-slideshow">
            <ul>
                <li data-background="images/cover.jpg">
                    <div class="flick-title">Welcome</div>
                    <div class="flick-sub-text">To our page</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="images/profile.jpg">
                <div class="flick-title">Who are we?</div>
                <div class="flick-sub-text">We are us</div>
            </li>

            <li data-background="images/friends.jpg">
                <div class="flick-title">Friends</div>
                <div class="flick-sub-text">Our friends</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And my javascript code is as follows:

```
Template.Slideshow.rendered = function() {
    $('.flicker-slideshow').flickerplate({
        arrows: true,
        arrows_constraint: false,
        auto_flick: true,
        auto_flick_delay: 10,
        block_text: true,
        dot_alignment: 'center',
        dot_navigation: true,
        flick_animation: 'transition-slide',
        flick_position: 1,
        theme: 'light'
        });
}
```

I get an error on the browser's console saying this:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Template.Slideshow.rendered (http://localhost:3000/client/views/slideshow.js?330e430ab7dab250766bdd68b706ee963571dc87:2:29)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:2924:21)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1720:14
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:2029:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?7b7ff7ee2ccdccd85a1ad0d8dc9d96193e29e8b0:1719:15
    at Tracker.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:438:11)
```

Comment: Sounds like flickerplate is undefined - how did you include it in your project?

Comment: Also, try using `this.$` instead of `$`, then it will only search inside the template.

Comment: I just added it to the compatibility folder.

Comment: Never mind. It was the this that was missing. The plugin has loaded :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stubailo suggested in the comments, all I needed was to add the this to the template.
So:

```
this.$('.flicker-slideshow').flickerplate();
```